# Birthday Chocolate HACKERRANK RUBY

Tags: ruby

This is the original link for the problem in hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-birthday-bar/problem

I have been fighting with this problem in Ruby and I don't know why my counter always returns `1`. This is the solution. I hope you can help me to understand what I'm making wrong.

```
s = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
d = 3
m = 2


def birthday(s, d, m)
    array = []
    cont = 0
    sum = 0
    m.times {array.push(s.shift)}
    (m-1).times do
        array.each {|i| sum = sum + i}
        if sum == d
            cont += 1 
        end
        array.shift
        array.push(s.shift)    
    end
    return cont
end

birthday(s, d, m)
```

Comment: It helps to give variables meaningful names *especially* when asking for our help. What is `m`? Month? Months? Moths? Memos?

Comment: Please don't put important information behind links. Links can change, or become unavailable. Make sure that everything that is needed to answer your question is *in the question*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the following does not answer your question directly, it is a Ruby-like way of solving the problem, especially by making use of the methods [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and [Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count).

```
def birthday(s, d, m)
  s.each_cons(m).count { |a| a.sum == d }
end
```

```
s = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
d = 3
m = 2    
birthday(s, d, m)
  #=> 2 ([1, 2] and [2, ])
```

```
s = [2, 2, 1, 3, 2]
d = 4
m = 2
birthday(s, d, m)
  #=> 2 ([2, 2] and [1, 3])
```

```
s = [2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 6, 1]
d = 9
m = 3
birthday(s, d, m)
  #=> 4 ([2, 4, 3], [4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 6] and [2, 6, 1])
```

Notice from the doc that when `each_cons` is used without a block it returns an enumerator:

```
s = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
d = 3
m = 2
enum = s.each_cons(m)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]:each_cons(2)>
```

`enum` will generate elements and pass them to `count` until there are no more to generate, at which time it raises a `StopIteration` exception:

```
enum.next #=> [1, 2] 
enum.next #=> [2, 1] 
enum.next #=> [1, 3] 
enum.next #=> [3, 2] 
enum.next #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end) <exception>
```

We can write<sup>1</sup>:

```
enum.count { |a| a.sum == d }
  #=> 2
```

After `enum` generates the first value (`[1, 2]`) the block variable `a` is assigned its value:

```
a = enum.next
  #=> [1, 2]
```

and the block calculation is performed. As

```
a.sum == d
  #=> [1, 2].sum == 3 => true
```

the count is incremented (from zero) by one. `enum` then passes each of its remaining values to `count` and the process is repeated. When, for example, `[1, 3].sum == 3 => false` is executed, the count is not incremented.

<sup>1. Note that since I just stepped through all the elements of `enum`, `enum.next` would generate another `StopIteration` exception. To execute `enum.count { |a| a.sum == d }` I therefore must first redefine the enumerator (`enum = s.each_cons(m)`) or [Enumerator#rewind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind) it: `enum.rewind`.</sup>

Comment: The only thing I'd like to change is the parameter names.

Comment: @Aetherus, I cannot disagree, but it could be worse: `string = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]`. I mindlessly took what had been offered.

Comment: Thanks, @CarySwoveland you have been really helpful for me, thanks to your answer I could learn more about Ruby.